# Not sure how this class works

Tags: java

I currently have to make a programme that plays the Chuck-a-Luck game.
Chuck a Luck is a dice game where a player can bet on what will appear on three six sided dice. The player starts with a certain amount of euros in their wallet or purse and can bet any whole number of euros, less than or equal to, the current amount of euros in their wallet or purse. The following table shows what a player can bet on and what they player will win if they  are correct:

The player can keep playing until either they run of money in their wallet or purse or decided to stop playing.

```
Wallet theWallet = new Wallet();
double cash = 10;

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You currently have €" + cash);

Object[] options = {"Any triple", "Big", "Field", "Small"};
int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"What type of bet would you like to place" , "Chuck-a-Luck", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,  JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,options,null);

String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much money would you like to bet? ");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
double money = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.close();

boolean enoughMoney = theWallet.get(money);
```

This is my code in the main line and this is the wallet class itself.

```
public class Wallet { // Wallet data type 
   // current cash in wallet 
   private double cash;  // invariant: cash >= 0.0 

   // construct wallet with zero cash 
   public Wallet() { cash = 0.0; } 

   // put an amount of money into wallet 
   // pre-condition: money > 0.0 
   public void put(double  money) { 
      assert money > 0.0 : "Wallet put method: pre-condition violated!"; 
      if (money > 0.0) cash = cash + money; 
   } 

   // get an amount of money from wallet 
   // returns true if wallet had enough cash, false otherwise 
   // pre-condition: money > 0.0 
   public boolean get(double money){ 
      assert money > 0.0 : "Wallet get method: pre-condition violated!"; 
      if (money > 0.0 && cash >= money) { 
         cash = cash - money; 
         return true; 
      } 
      return false; 
   } 

   // return current amount of cash in wallet 
   public double check() { return cash; } 

   // convert to a String data type value 
   public String toString() { 
      return getClass().getName() + "[cash = " + cash + "]"; 
   } 

} // end Wallet data type
```

Any valid bets I put in returns a boolean result of false whereas it should be true.
Say I had £10 and I place a bet of £5 it returns false where it should return true.
Any ideas on whats not working?
Thanks

Comment: In the future, please refrain from using mysterious question titles ("What's wrong with this class?" - what class? What's your problem with that class?). Instead, specify your exact problem ("Method returning false when it should return true" or something similar"). Your title shouldn't require us to actually read the question to know what the proble may be related to. We should have a good idea of what we're going to be answering by reading the title. Your current title could mean ANYTHING

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put some money inside your wallet first:

```
Wallet theWallet = new Wallet(); 
double cash = 10;
theWallet.put(cash);
```

Remember that the `cash` variable in the `main` method is not the same as the `cash` class variable inside the `Wallet` class:

```
public class Wallet { // Wallet data type 
   // current cash in wallet 
   private double cash;  // invariant: cash >= 0.0 

   // construct wallet with zero cash 
   public Wallet() { cash = 0.0; } 

   //rest of code  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You never added the cash to your wallet.

```
Wallet theWallet = new Wallet(); double cash = 10;
theWallet.put(cash); // MISSING!
```

So, you're out shopping with zero cash :)

```
public Wallet() { cash = 0.0; }
```